# what are some examples of ways graphs, trees, and other advanced data structures are used in database driven websites?

Tags: php, facebook, data-structures, relational-database, social-networking

So when  are simple `$array()` variables in your LAMP stack not enough? I'm sure these advanced data structures are useful but I'm wondering if someone can suggest some uses in a web context especially what one typically uses them for in social networking and similar data driven sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that, in any sufficiently complex system (web or not), different sets of data are used in different ways and at different times, and how the data is going to be used dictates the structure that is used. Trees, for example, are fast for looking things up in because a binary search is very efficient, and depending on the structure can also be fast at inserting, whereas a linked list is fast to insert/remove, but jumping to a particular point (as needed in a binary search) is very slow because you have to walk the list. On the flip-side, an array list is much faster at searching, but insert / delete can be very slow.

So, in a nutshell, the structures used primarily depend on the performance needs of the data being accessed, regardless of platform.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: a tree might be used in any situation where there are entities which have clear 'parents'.  For example, let's say you have an invite-only social network.  In this case you might structure the users as a tree, with a 'parent' entry in each user database entry.

Sorry if I've misunderstood your question, but it's awfully vague.  For cases of variables using trees, consider that we might iterate through the database in the above example and construct a tree out of the existing users to perform actions of some sort.